# PETSc non-linear solvers (SNES): specifying single Eval & Jacobian function

Tags: optimization, petsc, newton-method, jacobian

The PETSc [documentation example](https://petsc.org/release/manual/snes/) of a non-linear solver call has the user provide separate functions for the Jacobian and function evaluations:

```
    PetscCall(SNESSetFunction(snes, r, FormFunction2, NULL));
    PetscCall(SNESSetJacobian(snes, J, J, FormJacobian2, NULL));
```

In my case, it would be most convenient to compute simultaneously the Jacobian and cost function (and use a flag). This is because my Jacobian function already computes the function at 0 cost.

I searched for "SNESSet" in the hopes there might exist a SNESSetFunctionAndJacobian or some such, but this does not seem to be the case. Does this option exist under another name? Or is there a simple work-around I'm not thinking of?

Comment: They probably do it this way as they evaluate the Residual more often than the Jacobian and the Jacobian is usually much more expensive to compute.  Probably better to ask on PETSc mailing list, but you could just create wrapper functions around your Jacobian+Residual routine to test.

Comment: Yes, but that could also be handled by passing a flag: 1, compute Jacobian + function, 0 only compute function.

If that had been done, one could have still defined an on-the-spot lambda (or otherwise function) if Jacobian and cost function implementations are completely separate, and be done with an if statement. 

Thank you for the suggestion, I will turn to their mailing list.